# overlayroot-chroot on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I used to use `overlayroot-chroot` in Ubuntu:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/overlayroot-chroot.8.html

But now that I have changed to Debian it is not there, and `sudo apt install overlayroot-chroot` does not find it.

How does one get it for Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this binary sub-package [was removed from the Debian builds in 2014](https://salsa.debian.org/cloud-team/cloud-initramfs-tools/-/commit/dd4caa97148432cba60eb06d5b554a6c8926f968) because at this time there was no *overlayfs* compiled on Debian. Current Debian 11 kernels do provide *overlayfs*.

Then it appears Launchpad has [something wrong for these sources](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-initramfs-tools):

> cloud-initramfs-tools 0.18 is older than the current packaged version.
> Launchpad may be missing release information for the trunk series or
> this package is linked to the wrong cloud-initramfs-tools series.

while 0.47 is available. Debian never went past 0.18 which might or might not be a coincidence.

You could rebuild:

- either from Debian sources

  ```
  apt-get source cloud-initramfs-tools
  ```

  You'll have to uncomment the build part for package `overlayroot` in the file `cloud-initramfs-tools-*/debian/control` and hope nothing important was adjusted later between 0.18 and 0.47.

  Whatever extra is built, you should install only the newly built `overlayroot_*.deb` package (using `apt-get` rather than `dpkg` so dependencies are still pulled in).
- or from Ubuntu Launchpad sources:

  Easiest would be by downloading from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-initramfs-tools/0.47ubuntu1 the `.tar.xz` and `.dsc` files and using:

  ```
  dpkg-source -x cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.dsc
  ```

Then in both cases follow guide on how to (re)build a package from source: https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial including steps 2 (dependencies) and 4 (edit the source if needed).

Caveat: not tested, no guarantee about the resulting behavior.

See also:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732788#40
- https://salsa.debian.org/cloud-team/cloud-initramfs-tools/-/merge_requests/5

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. Managed to reubild and install it, but when I try to use it it fails with:  "Unable to find the overlayroot lowerdir", as shown here: https://github.com/larsks/cloud-initramfs-tools/blob/d9fce7f8975009cc1b67fd7fd1ca2008bf5c97cd/overlayroot/usr/sbin/overlayroot-chroot#L41

Comment: @run_the_race With a cursory glance, looks like this command is not intended to do any setup for overlayfs, but is expecting such setup to already exist, so one can do modifications on the part kept normally read-only.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but I see 'overlayroot` seems to be part of cloud-initramfs-tools overlay package of tools. And I think `overlayroot is supposed to setup the overlay file system.

Comment: actually it works! The `apt-get source` method install the 0.18 version, trying the alternate method (at first didnt work for me, but having gotten the wrong version right was not able to retry) of using Ubuntu's tar.xy/.dsc installed version 0.47 and it worked!

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer 10 times, thank you so much, this is such a huge help, I will get much more sleep thanks to you. Would have never gotten there without your help, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some expanded detail instructions to the process @A.B supplied:

## Build Ubuntu Overlayroot-chroot for Debian from Ubuntu

- `sudo apt install overlayroot` not available in Debian
- `overlayroot` (enables overlayfs) and `overlayroot-chroot` (allows one to make changes to file system) are part of `cloud-initramfs-tools`

### CREATE A DIR FOR THE BUILD

`mkdir ~/overlayroot; cd ~/overlayroot`

### GET SOURCE CODE

- Using Ubuntu Repo to get `cloud-initramfs-tools` 0.47 (0.18 will not work!)
- Get the files from: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-initramfs-tools/0.47ubuntu1

```
wget -O cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.dsc https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/cloud-initramfs-tools/0.47ubuntu1/cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.dsc
wget -O cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.tar.xz https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/cloud-initramfs-tools/0.47ubuntu1/cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.tar.xz
```

### UNPACKAGE THE APP

`dpkg-source -x cloud-initramfs-tools_0.47ubuntu1.dsc`

### BUILD THE APP

`debuild -b -uc -us`

### INSTALL THE APP

`sudo apt install -y ../overlayroot_0.47ubuntu1_all.deb`

### CONFIGURE OVERLAYROOT

- Set `/etc/overlayroot.conf` as required, e.g.:

  ```
  overlayroot_cfgdisk="disabled"
  overlayroot="tmpfs:swap=1,recurse=0"
  ```
- Reboot

### NOTES

- Can make permanent changes using:
  sudo overlayroot-chroot

Comment: Great answer, really helped me out. A few remarks that could be adjusted:
- install package `dpkg-dev` if `dpkg-source` is not available
- install package `devscripts` if `debuild` is not available
- run the `debuild` command from inside the dir created by the `dpkg-source` command